# Uploading images from Azure blob storage to Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, azure, azure-blob-storage

So I know it's possible to grab images from Azure blob storage and getting all the links, but would it be possible to retrieve all the images and upload them to WordPress Media Library?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try doing a quick search online before posting here, but yes I believe this should be possible.

Assuming you already have your images in Azure

- get the [Windows Azure Storage for WordPress Plugin](https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/windows-azure-storage/)
- grab the access key from Azure, you can find this under Azure Storage Account’s  **Settings** > **Access Keys**  blade)
- in WordPress **settings**, under **Windows Azure**, put in the Azure credentials you just grabbed
- create a new container in WordPress, and select *'Use Windows Azure Storage when uploading via WordPress’*
- now that you have the plugin installed and configured you should be able to once in the WordPress Edit screen you can just go **Add Media** button > **Insert Media** > **U[load Files** tab and you'll be able to now point to Azure Blob Storage and grab images

Comment: Just in case anyone will try this be aware that this plugin struggles with v2 accounts: "If a Storage account is created with the new Azure portal, authentication will fail,". I would not recommend to use this in your Azure environment.

Comment: what do you recommend then ?